# Vector Calculus Notation for "Gradient of a Vector"

Tags: derivatives, notation, vector-analysis

Given (differentiable) functions $\,n_{1,2}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\,$ we write vector
$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}$

\begin{align}
  \vec{\boldsymbol{n}} = \begin{bmatrix} n_{1} \\ n_{2} \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

and define  *"gradient of a vector"* operation $\,:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}\,$ as

\begin{align}\label{1}\tag{$\boldsymbol{\ast}$}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \,^{\partial}/_{\partial x}\, \\ \,^{\partial}/_{\partial y}\,
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}\,n_{1} & n_{2} \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix}\, 
    \big(n_{1}\big)_{x} & \big(n_{2}\big)_{x} \\\,
    \big(n_{1}\big)_{y} & \big(n_{2}\big)_{y}
  \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Is it possible to write the expression above in terms of nabla operator and vector $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{n}}$?
For example, I was thinking about something like

\begin{align}
  \begin{bmatrix}\, 
    \big(n_{1}\big)_{x} & \big(n_{2}\big)_{x} \\\,
    \big(n_{1}\big)_{y} & \big(n_{2}\big)_{y}
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \nabla \circ \vec{\boldsymbol{n}}^{T}
\end{align}

where $\,\circ\,$ stands for some (*vector calculus?*) operation.

What would be an appropriate symbol to write instead of $\,\circ\,$? 
Is there standard notation for such operation?

I know that the matrix on the right hand side of equation $\eqref{1}$ can be viewed as Jacobian matrix of vector-valued function $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{n}}\,(x,y):\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2},\,$ but I would like to be able to express in using just the vector $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{n}}\,$ and differential operations of vector calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there exist actually a standard notation for that. If you look up into a **tensor calculus book** and read a little about the **Tensor Product** or **Dyadic Product** or sometimes called **the outer product of vectors**, $ \otimes $, you will find what you want. Usually, it is written in this way

$\nabla  \otimes {\bf{n}} \equiv \nabla {\bf{n}}$

where the second one is mostly used for abbreviation! [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics)) may help you a little. Also, see [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del). [This book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319163413) by **Itskov** is a good one if you want to see the theory and application at the same time. Also, if you are some rigorous mathematician you can take [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387967907) by **Marsden**.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\,\nabla\otimes{\bf{n}} \equiv \nabla {\bf{n}}^{T}$?

Comment: @Vlad: It depends on the basic definitions! Both can be true! :) I have seen both them in several books.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you! Could you also give a link to a __tensor calculus book__, or list its authors and title of relevant book you would recommend?

Comment: @Vlad: See the link added to answer! :) Hope it helps

Comment: @Vlad: I suggested **two** books depending on what you want. The book by **Marsden** is more rigorous! :)

Comment: @Vlad: Are you there? :D

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! Also, do you know by chance how to write out hessian matrix in similar manner?

Comment: @Vlad: Your answer is ${\bf{H}} = \nabla  \otimes \nabla  \otimes {\bf{n}} \equiv \nabla \nabla {\bf{n}}$. :)